# How can I call contract method that suicide and continue execution?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, selfdestruct

Can I call another contract that eventually will call selfdestruct, and keep executing my function?

For example, say I have two contracts as follows:

```
contract Destructor {
    address owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function done() public {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}

contract Test {
    ...
    function test(address dtor) public returns(bool) {
        Destructor(dtor).done();
        // Can I keep execution here after dtor was destructed?
        bla += 42;
        return true;
    }
}
```

will `bla += 42;` be executed and `test()` will return `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Here's a cleaned up version of the contracts.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.2;

contract Destructor {

    address payable owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function done() public {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}

contract Test {

    uint public bla;

    function test(address dtor) public returns(bool) {
        Destructor(dtor).done();
        bla += 42;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is `42` in Remix to show it working.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!
So I could just try to run my test instead of asking here :)